# Writing QGIS Plugin or function to find/pan/zoom to coordinate generated from number that has geolocation basis for its creation?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

In my area, PINs (Parcel Id Numbers) are 10-digit numbers built from the coordinate of the centroid of the parcel (polygon).  I have no coding experience, but I know what I need is fairly straightforward and hope someone can help me.

Note- the 10-digit PIN is NOT a coordinate, it is an encoded coordinate and the actual coordinate would need to parsed out.

What I wish to do is create an input field labeled 'PIN Search' where a user can input a 10-digit PIN and after hitting enter the program would determine the coordinate and, ideally, select the nearest polygon at that coordinate and zoom/pan to its extent.  I would be happy if it would just zoom/pan to the coordinate at some predetermined scale.

I suppose I need to learn to write some python code.  I have no idea how to create an input field, I know what to do with the data to generate a coordinate, but then I would like to select the nearest polygon to that location and pan/zoom to its extent.  I would be happy to just pan/zoom to the coordinate, though.

Is this something I would need to create a plugin for or can it be done in some sort of macro?

**EDIT**
--How a PIN becomes a coordinate
CRS = NAD83 / North Carolina (ftUS)  EPSG = 2264

extents: xmin = 400000, ymin = 400000, xmax = 1300000, ymax = 1300000

PIN is 10-digit number of the form x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4 x5 y5
The coordinate is derived as X=x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6, Y=y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 where x6 and y6 are = 0 and if x1 = 0,1,2,or 3 then 10 is added and if y1 = 0,1,2,3 then 10 is added.  Examples:  PIN = 9876543210 generates coordinate x=975310, y=864200:  PIN = 0123456789 generates coordinate x= 1024680, y= 1135790

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a PIN and how it becomes a coordinate? In which Coordinate System Reference are your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by creating a Plug In with the following code.

```
    def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    self.dlg.PINvalue.setFocus()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # get the PIN from the dialog box
        pin =self.dlg.PINvalue.text()
        scale = 1000
        if len(pin)<10:
            QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"Error","Not a valid input")
            return
        #compute coordinates
        x1 = pin[0]
        y1 = pin[1]
        if int(x1) < 5:
            x1 = '1' + x1
        if int(y1) < 5:
            y1 = '1' + y1
        Coordx = x1 + pin[2] + pin[4] + pin[6] + pin[8] + '0'
        Coordy = y1 + pin[3] + pin[5] + pin[7] + pin[9] + '0'      
        # create a rectangle to sort features by. Qgis will find overlapping features
        # it's ok that xmin & xmax are the same and ymin & ymax are the same.
        filterRect = QgsRectangle(
                float(Coordx),
                float(Coordy), 
                float(Coordx),
                float(Coordy))
        projectRoot = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
        parcelGroup = projectRoot.findGroup("Parcels") # replace with actual group name

        featFound = False

        for lyr in parcelGroup.findLayers():
            try:
                # get feature iterator and select first one that overlaps
                featFound = lyr.layer().getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(filterRect)).next()
                lyr.layer().select(featFound.id())

            except StopIteration:
                # if none do just move on
                pass

        if featFound: # will still be false if no feature was found
            mapExtentRect = featFound.geometry().boundingBox()
        else:
            mapExtentRect = QgsRectangle(
                float(Coordx) - scale,
                float(Coordy) - scale, 
                float(Coordx) + scale,
                float(Coordy) + scale)
        mc=self.iface.mapCanvas() 
        # Set the extent to our new rectangle
        mc.setExtent(mapExtentRect)
        # Refresh the map
        mc.refresh()
```